# Fancybox3 second link launches link around image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-3

Using Fancybox 3.0 and I have a gallery of images with text under the thumbnails. Instead of opening the images when clicking on either the thumbnail or the text, it opens an iframe for that image with information on that image and gives the user the ability to go left and right through the images as if it was an image gallery but with iframes instead. My issue is that the link that wraps around the thumbnail makes it so that when the iframe is opened, I get a nice list of thumbnails via fancybox on the side of the screen... but when I click on the text at the bottom I get the iframe but no list of images. I assume this is because of the fact that the first link is wrapped around the image. I can't make the entire DIV a link for the fancybox as I have other links under the thumbnail (to favorite the image). I have to set the thumbnail link and the text link to different galleries (IE data-fancybox="gallery1" and data-fancybox="gallery2") so I'm not doubling up the links when you go left and right through them all.

**So how can I get the text link to trigger the image link instead so if you click on the thumbnail or the text link it triggers the same iframe for that image?**

Here's the code I have, dumbed down a bit since there are php variables.

```
<div class="ImageBox">
    <a data-fancybox="gallery1" data-type="iframe" data-src="imgpop.php?ImageID=<?=$CurrentImageName?>" href="javascript:;">
          <div class="GImgBox"><THUMBNAIL></div>
    </a>
  <div class="GCaption">
    <a href="javascript:fav('<?=$CurrentImageName?>')">
          <FAVORITE>
    </a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery2" data-type="iframe" data-src="imgpop.php?ImageID=<?=$CurrentImageName?>" href="javascript:;">
          <IMAGE NAME>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like when I click on the image link:

[image: Here's what it looks like when I click on the image link:]

Here's what it looks like when I click on the text link:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using iframes to display images? To display the info? Why don't you use caption for that?

Comment: Because there's a form for filling out information on that iframe with the image. Caption can't be that advanced.

Comment: Since it is possible to have multiple active instances, I would suggest to add custom button in the toolbar (or in the caption) so that clicking it would display your form over the image (similarly how "Share" button works). It would look much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data-thumb` attribute for thumbnail image.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! Wish this was documented in the fancybox docs. Would be really helpful.